# Crash for PFUser.query() force unwrap

Tags: parse-platform, swift2, crash-reports, crashlytics, symbolicatecrash

Background

- Parse 1.8.5 iOS SDK
- Xcode 7.0.1 (7A1001)
- Swift 2

In my code, I subclassed PFUser (named as MyUser), and try to create the query using `MyUser.query()`. It returns me `PFQuery?`

```
let query = MyUser.query()
query!.whereKey("username", containedIn: ["a", "b"])
query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
  ...
})
```

I then submitted this to App Store Review, and being rejected 4 times (taking me 4 weeks), and they kept reporting the app crashes around here. It's been very frustrating. After checking with Crashlytics, it says the below line is raising `EXC_BREAKPOINT`.

```
query!.whereKey("username", containedIn: ["a", "b"])
```

The crash log from Apple says it is `EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)`, that implies `a non-optional type with a nil value` according to [TN2151](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html). In fact the symbolicated version of the crash logs provided by Apple shows line number to be 0.

I checked [Parse documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-querying), the returned `PFQuery` is not optional. I wonder what is the best practice to implement this logic.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried to subclass a `PFObject` before but as I checked the documentation, the query method `(PF_NULLABLE PFQuery *)query` clearly returns a Nullable `PFQuery` object which will be treated by Swift as an optional. (see [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/query)) It also says that the subclass can only call this method if it conforms to [PFSubclassing](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Protocols/PFSubclassing.html) protocol.

Generally when there is an optional, you really need something like an `if let` to protect yourself against a `nil` being returned.